# Azure Data Factory Monitor showing no data for Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have two ADF pipelines. When I run them in debug, I can see them in the Pipeline runs tab (Debug part). So if I run a pipeline 10 times, I will have 10 entries. However, my Dashboard is empty. Even after waiting, doing several refreshes, I have "No result - There are no records to show you right now." in Pipeline, Activity and Trigger runs. I am Owner on the ressource.

[empty dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cLfq.png)

I could not find anything on the web, except for the IAM part.

Thanks for your help

Comment: which browser did you use? Did you try close and reopen the data factory?

Comment: Any other ways, you can check the Data Factory active log to see it there are pipelines be executed.

Comment: I tried with different browsers, same problem. Even in the Overview panel for the Data Factory ressource, in the Monitoring part, I have nothing for PiplineRuns / ActivityRuns. It's strange because I successfully ran multiple pipelines.

Comment: that's strange, can you ask Azure support to get help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it would appear that the dashboard shows only triggered pipeline runs (and not debug one). You need to trigger your pipeline (Add Trigger -> Trigger Now) if you want to be able to test that the Monitoring is working. That was driving me crazy.